# Parsing event logs from VMTrace in trace_call

Tags: events, evm, openethereum, trace

There are 3 return values in `trace_call`. State Diff and Trace seem pretty straight forward. However, VMTRace's output contains 2 values - `code` and `ops`. Code looks something like this

```
"0x6080604052600436106102a45760003560e01c80639b2c0a371161016e578063dee00f35116100cb578063f100b2051161007f578063f2d5d56b11610064578063f2d5d56b146...
```

Its the opcodes that were executed in the function call. And the Ops look like this

```json
[
    {
        "cost": 3,
        "ex": {
            "mem": null,
            "push": [
                "0x80"
            ],
            "store": null,
            "used": 235217
        },
        "pc": 0,
        "sub": null
    },
    {
        "cost": 3,
        "ex": {
            "mem": null,
            "push": [
                "0x40"
            ],
            "store": null,
            "used": 235214
        },
        "pc": 2,
        "sub": null
    },
    
    //more such entries

]
```

For some of the ops, `sub` field is not `null` and contains the ops for the nested function call.

My question is - how to parse the event logs from this? I understand that I can look at the opcodes for log0, log1.. and so. But is there any library that could do that for me? Or is there a simpler method to get the event logs for a simulated transaction?

Comment: apparently I asked the same question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72064656/extracting-emitted-events-logs-from-geth-transaction-trace-debug-tracecall Have you figured this out & mind to share?